# Different operations of different elements of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a column vector that have multiple values, e.g 100. Also I have a vector with some indices, but they are numbers not logical values (I get them from another calculation). Let's say the values are 13,44,77. Now I want to increase the three values at those indices by 10%, and decrease everything else by 10%.
Eventually I will have successively increase/decrease the values of the previous vector using a loop, but for the time being let's just say I do it only once. 
I have done this but through a for loop as follows: (My original vector is T, and the indices vector is A)

```
P=[];
for k = 1:size(T,1)
if ismember(k,A)
    q=T(k).*1.1;
else
    q=T(k).*0.9;
end
P=[P;q];

end
```

This way I get the new vector in P. My question, is there another faster and more efficient way to do this without a loop? because as I said, I'll eventually need to do this one many columns not only once

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume all values will be reduced by 10%, then overwrite the values at the desired indices with the original T values increased by 10%:

```
P = T * 0.9;
P(A) = T(A) * 1.1;
```

Alternatively, (especially if you're going to use the same indices on several columns) create a vector of values to multiply with the original vector:

```
F = ones(size(T,1), 1) * 0.9;
F(A) = 1.1;
P = T .* F;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That cut the running time tremendously. Can't thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

You can build a function called `ifelse`, not only this time, but can be used in many occasions I think.

```
function result = ifelse(condition, trueResult, falseResult)
%IFELSE input condition, ifture returns trueResult, vice versa
narginchk(3,3);  % check correct number of input args, min = 3, max = 3
if condition
    result = trueResult;
else
    result = falseResult; 
end
```

Based on the answer from @beaker above, I compare the 3 methods and it shows overwriting is the fastest, arrayfun at the second place the for loop at last:

```
T = (1:90)';
A = [3;4;7;18;22;39;46;55;81];

% first method:using ifelse
P1 = arrayfun(@(x, y, z) ifelse(x, y, z), (ismember(1:size(T), A))',  T * 1.1, T * 0.9);

% second: using for loop
P2=[];
for k = 1:size(T,1)
if ismember(k,A)
    q=T(k).*1.1;
else
    q=T(k).*0.9;
end
P2=[P2;q];

end

% third and fastest one: assining and overwriting
P3 = T * 0.9;
P3(A) = T(A) * 1.1;
```

You can choose for your convenience.